# SQL Query to find the number of entries for all tournaments in 2012?

Tags: mysql, sql

My schema is:

CREATE TABLE entry (
MemberID int NOT NULL,
TourID int NOT NULL,
Year int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (MemberID,TourID,Year)
);

```
        INSERT INTO entry VALUES (118,24,2011),(228,24,2012),(258,24,2011),(286,24,2010), 
        (286,24,2011),(286,24,2012),(415,24,2012),(228,25,2012),(239,25,2012),(415,25,2010), 
        (228,36,2012),(415,36,2011),(415,36,2012),(235,38,2010),(235,38,2012),(258,38,2011), 
        (415,38,2010),(415,38,2012),(235,40,2011),(235,40,2012),(239,40,2010),(415,40,2010), 
        (415,40,2011),(415,40,2012);

      CREATE TABLE tournament (
      TourID int NOT NULL,
      TourName varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      TourType varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      Active char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (TourID)
      );

     INSERT INTO tournament VALUES (24,'London','Social','Y'),(25,'Leeds','Social','Y'), 
     (36,'Bath','Open','Y'),(38,'Liverpool','Open','N'),(40,'Birminigham','Open','Y');
```

I want to get tournament id and number of entries for all tournaments in 2012?

So far I have tried this below code:

```
      SELECT tourid, COUNT(year) FROM entry WHERE year = 2012 GROUP BY tourid;


            

             |  tourid  |  count  |
             ______________________ 
             |    24    |   3     |
             |    25    |   2     |
             |    36    |   2     |
             |    38    |   2     |
             |    40    |   2     |
             ______________________
```

and getting the above value... I am not sure whether it is right or not. Would someone please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Does the table `entry` have 3 rows of `tourid=24` for year=2012 in it? [The answer is Yes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6ff6cecdb48fefd544924006d957e4cd)

Comment: Yes 3 rows of 24 for year 2012.

Comment: Then do the next checking for the other tourid. If all have corresponding rows of the count result, then its correct. For me, I usually do `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(column)` though. Didn't seem to be any different. Some people do `COUNT(1)`.

Comment: Got it. one more thing, how do I add the TourName to get the names of tournaments?

Comment: That you use `JOIN`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your condition with showing tourname, try this:

```
 SELECT entry.tourid, tournament.tourname, COUNT(year) 
 FROM entry 
 JOIN tournament ON entry.tourid=tournament.tourid
 WHERE year = 2012 
 GROUP BY entry.tourid, tournament.tourname;
```

Use [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) on identical column. Here its `TourID`.

You can make it a bit better (shorter/easier to write) by assigning aliases to the tables.

```
SELECT A.tourid, B.tourname, 
       COUNT(*) -- columns in SELECT also can assign alias like "COUNT(*) AS Cn" etc.
 FROM entry AS A -- you can either assign table alias "entry AS A" or simply "entry A" 
 JOIN tournament AS B 
   ON A.tourid=B.tourid
 WHERE A.year = 2012 
 GROUP BY A.tourid, B.tourname;
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fe16b13e0a0dd2329300573227f3fe32)